# Android 4.1.2 or Google APIs (4.1.2)

Tags: android, sdk

I am using intelliJ and want to target 4.1.2 android version. In IntelliJ when it gives me the choice it gives me two 4.1.2 build target choices

- Android 4.1.2
- Google APIs (4.1.2)

What's the difference?

Thanks

Comment: thanks @squonk. I was thinkng that this question must have been answered before but I just couldnot see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would almost always want to target Google Android Api, which includes Google Service support (google play, maps, gtalk...).

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15859617/2783104) answer.

One exception is if your device is not Google certified (which you can check [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en)), or if you dont want Google API support and still prefer to target regular Android API.

From a comment in the other answer [here's](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en) the list of devices that are supported

Comment: "You would almost always want to target Google Android Api..." : Why? I can think of very many apps I might develop which have absolutely no need for any of the Google APIs.

Comment: @SuppressWarnings. Thanks for quick answer! Can you help with my comment on the other answer? Thanks

Comment: @Squonk Yes, well, I meant that nowaday most apps make use of google api in one way or another, so most of the time you're targeting Google Android API by default (at least I do). Still, I edited my answer with clarification. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Android 4.1.2 is just stock android. Google APIs is what the name says. It includes Google APIs that you might want to use. e.g. Google Maps API.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. If I use the google apis does this mean that i wont be able to run it on a kindle as this has its own store and doesnt use play. Thinking about this I think kindle is the only big supplier that does not have play

Comment: Maps API requires one to have store installed.

Comment: @RNJ It will run if the device is google certified. You can check wether it is certified or not [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en). Else you will have to target regular Android API.